# How to access windows 7 remotely from ubuntu?

Tags: windows, vnc

I can't seem to connect remotely to a friend's windows machine using vinagre.

My friend is using realvnc free edition as a server and he operates windows 7.

So how can I set it up so that I can remotely access his desktop?

Answer (score 2):

You could try Remmina - http://remmina.sourceforge.net/. It works very well for me and is available in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: Could one use Remmina to connect to Windows instances of Azure / Google Cloud / AWS using RDP?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Teamviewer? It's not FOSS but if I recall it works pretty well.